# Is there any corresponding word in English?

Tags: word-request

In my mother language, there is a word to describe a phenomenon.

Most people in a forum have basically the same opinion toward a certain issue or they take the same attitude to a thing, while in other forums, people don't think that way. Because people always go to the same forum, they thought everyone thinks everything the same way as they think.

In my mother language, this phenomenon is called the "stratosphere".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You describe the usage of the term in your language:

> Because people always go to the same forum, they thought everyone thinks everything the same way as they think.

The term **echo chamber** describes what you are talking about exactly. [Wikipedia says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_%28media%29)

> In discussions of news media, an **echo chamber** refers to situations in which beliefs are amplified or reinforced by communication and repetition inside a closed system and insulated from rebuttal. By participating in an echo chamber, people are able to seek out information that reinforces their existing views without encountering opposing views, potentially resulting in an unintended exercise in confirmation bias. Echo chambers may increase social and political polarization and extremism.

They begin the article by talking about news media, but the phenomenon is also very prevalent in social media where users have "feeds" that are curated by themselves or by the system, e.g. Twitter, Reddit, Facebook, etc. People may also choose to visit specific websites and forums that reflect their existing views.

[This webpage](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/digital-media-literacy/what-is-an-echo-chamber/1/) from the Digital Media Literacy project discusses echo chambers.

Comment: Thank you!! That is 100% the same as what I want to say.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [**groupthink**](https://www.britannica.com/science/groupthink), although that is mostly about the group all thinking the same more than them believing that others don't think that way.

Comment: Thank you @stangdon~~

Answer (score 1):

You describe the "birds of a feather" phenomenon. AKA Sheeple. It's human nature to congregate with those that share our views. That's how societies continue to exist over time. When our beliefs become so disparate they no longer support the common good then it becomes a problem, i.e. dissenters.

Comment: Thank you @abandoned at birth~~